# Показать/скрыть элемент списка

Tags: php, css

Сразу оговорюсь, что данный функционал мне нужно реализовать именно на PHP. Суть такова: у меня есть список, с каждым элементом которого выводиться кнопка, при нажатии на которую скрывается/показывается ДАННЫЙ элемент списка. Мне нужно самое тривиальное из всех существующих решений, чтобы я понял как это работает. Я пока что реализовал так, что скрываются показываются ВСЕ элементы, не важно рядом с каким нажата кнопка, а применить стиль к конкретному элементу не получается, хотя идентификатор для каждой записи передаю верно. Свой код сюда выкладывать не хочется, чтобы он не стал претендентом на звание "самый нелогичный быдлокод в мире", поэтому буду рад, если кто-нибудь предложит что-то готовое или наставит на путь истинный.

Comment: выкладывай)) тут такого полно.

Comment: Скажу так - кнопка с каждым элементом <li> является ссылкой, в которой GET-параметром передается некое значение. Если это значение передано, то меняю стиль элемента, вид кнопки и (ВНИМАНИЕ!) сам GET-параметр на другой, чтобы потом так же обратиться к нему и изменить стиль и кнопку на начальную. В итоге меняется стиль для всех <li>, а мне нужно изменить именно для того, рядом с которым нажата кнопка.

PS. Список вывожу циклом и на каждый новый <li> передаю уникальный id.

Comment: > Сразу оговорюсь, что данный функционал мне нужно реализовать именно на PHP

Сразу не хочу вас огорчать, но все же данный функционал вам придется реализовывать на javascript!

Comment: @Palmervan, я только учусь и поэтому в данный момент меня интересует именно PHP. Пусть это будет с перезагрузкой страницы, пусть будет криво и не красиво, но на PHP.

Comment: Можно же с перезагрузкой браузера:))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то типа этого?

```
    <?php
// стартуем сессию
session_start();

/* Инициализация переменных */
$taskId = null;

// массив в которых держим все задания которые были кликнуты на странице
$clickedTasks = array();

// массив с заданиями
$tasks = array(
    'Task1',
    'Task2',
    'Task3',
    'Task4',
    'Task5',
    'Task6'
);

// если в сессии еще нет массива с кликнутыми заданиями - инициализируем
if(!isset($_SESSION['clickedTasks'])) {
    $_SESSION['clickedTasks'] = array();
} else {

    // у нас есть массив в сессии копируем в локальную переменную для удобства
    $clickedTasks = $_SESSION['clickedTasks'];
}

// если кто-то нажал на какое-то задание
if(isset($_GET['task_id']) && trim($_GET['task_id']) !== "") {
    $taskId = intval($_GET['task_id']);
}
/* Конец инициализации */

// добавляем логику по которой определяем какой статус у данного задания: будет оно скрыто или показываться на странице
// и соотвественно обновляем массив
if(!isset($clickedTasks[$taskId]) || $clickedTasks[$taskId] === true) {
    $clickedTasks[$taskId] = false;
} else {
    $clickedTasks[$taskId] = true;
}

// обновляем массив в сессии в соотвествии
$_SESSION['clickedTasks'] = $clickedTasks;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
            foreach($tasks as $key => $task) {

                // всегда обновляем значения знака, который будет стоять перед заданием на "по умолчанию"
                $sign = '-';

                // смотрим, если выьранное задание в скрытом режиме - меняем символ и убираем задание
                if(isset($clickedTasks[$key]) && $clickedTasks[$key] === false) {
                    $sign = '+';
                    $task = "";
                }

                // выводим все на экран
                echo '<li><a href="?task_id=' . $key . '" class="button">' . $sign . '</a> ' . $task . '</li>';
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, именно то, что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @knes - я, типа, автор ответа :)

Comment: типа да. Но я править каменты не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Итак.

Если кратко, то:

```
<?php
$node_id = 144;
printf('<li id="node_%s">',$node_id);

  if(isset($_GET['node_'.$node_id]) && $_GET['node_'.$node_id]='show'){
    print('<a href="/this_page.php">скрыть</a>');
    print('<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>');
  }else{
    printf('<a href="/this_page.php?node_%s=show">показать</a>',$node_id);
  }
?>
</li>
```

Все это в цикле, ес-но.

НО. лучше и правда на JS.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас нужного кода нет под рукой, завтра обязательно попробую. И еще - сейчас вот так с ходу не могу понять что делает данный код, можете кратко объяснить логику? А по поводу JS - я просто с ним пока что вообще не знаком, поэтому не хочу туда лезть.

Comment: @knes, что-то не получается. Вот смотри: я вывожу массив в виде списка, рядом с каждым элементом списка у меня выводится кнопка:


$content = '-';
echo "<ul>";
foreach($tasks as $task){
   echo "<a href='#' class='button'>$content</a> <li>$task</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";


Что мне нужно: чтобы при нажатии на кнопку рядом с определенным элементом списка, этот элемент скрывался (display: none) и $content менялся на '+', при повторном нажатии происходило все в точности наоборот.

PS. на самом деле в моем случае выводится дерево, но мне не хотелось усложнять код, принцип остается такой же.

Comment: > А по поводу JS - я просто с ним пока что вообще не знаком, поэтому не хочу туда лезть.

а пора уже, если возникают такие задачи

Comment: До сих пор не получается решить проблему. Последний комментарий остается в силе. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: @knes лучше на css :)